# Generate documentation from object mappings metadata for documentation?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm interested in finding out if it is possible to generate documentation from code using reflection. I'm specifically interested in mapping assignments I use within a method. Ideally I would like to capture the method name for grouping purposes and then any object property assignment within that method. Ideally I would then also capture the assigned object property.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PrintMethodContents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Paladin newPaladin = new Paladin()
            {
                Height = 5.6,
                Stones = 300
            };

            Warlock newWarlock = new Warlock()
            {
                Height = 5.6,
                Stones = 250
            };

            ICharacterClass convertedCharacter = CharacterClassConversion.ConvertCharacterClass(
                                                newPaladin, 
                                                CharacterClasses.WARLOCK);

            System.Type type = convertedCharacter.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] myArray = type.GetProperties();

            Console.Write("Printing Properties for Object " + type.Name + "\n");
            foreach (PropertyInfo myParam in myArray)
            {
                Console.Write(myParam.Name + "\n");
            }

        }
    }

    public enum CharacterClasses
    {
        WARLOCK,
        PALADIN
    }

    public static class CharacterClassConversion
    {
        public static ICharacterClass ConvertCharacterClass(ICharacterClass originClass, CharacterClasses classType)
        {
            switch (classType)
            {
                case CharacterClasses.WARLOCK:
                    Warlock newWarlock = new Warlock
                    {
                        Height = originClass.Height,
                        Stones = originClass.Stones
                    };

                    return newWarlock;
                case CharacterClasses.PALADIN:
                    Paladin newPaladin = new Paladin
                    {
                        Height = originClass.Height,
                        Stones = originClass.Stones
                    };

                    return newPaladin;
                default:
                    return originClass;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ICharacterClass
    {
        double Height { get; set; }
        double Stones { get; set; }
    }

    class Paladin : ICharacterClass
    {
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Stones { get; set; }
    }

    class Warlock : ICharacterClass
    {
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Stones { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to get to the point where my output looks something like the following.

```
CharacterClassConversion
    WARLOCK
        Height came from originClass Height
        Stones came from originClass Stones
    Paladin
        Height came from originClass Height
        Stones came from originClass Stones
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have time for a proper answer, but you might try checking out:

- The Mono.Cecil library for analyzing the IL bytecode: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/
- The Roslyn API for analyzing the C# code: https://joshvarty.com/2015/03/24/learn-roslyn-now-control-flow-analysis/

Comment: Excellent resources. I'll take a look. Thanks